# "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0" with ArrayList?

Tags: java, arraylist

"Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0" is the main error I get when I compile this method:

```
public static ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> createSparseArray(int len, double den) {
    int counter = 0;
    ArrayList<Integer> placeHolder = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    for (int j = 0; j < len; j++) {
        double randomNumber = Math.random();
        if (randomNumber < den) {
            counter++;
            placeHolder.add(j);
        }
    }
    ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> list = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>();
    for (int k = 0; k < counter; k++) {
        for (int m = 0; m < 2; m++) {
            list.get(0).set(placeHolder.get(k), (int) (Math.random() * (99999) + 1));
        }
    }
    return list;
}
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: The new `list` doesn't contain any item in it. `list.get(0)` will result in Exception. First add the empty `ArrayList` in `list` then use it.

Answer (score 6):

`ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> list` doesnt contain any element in (0)th postion  and the compiler throws out of bounds exception on iterating when it doesn't find any element in the specified postion.

when you try executing `list.get(0).set(placeHolder.get(k), (int) (Math.random() * (99999) + 1));` statement , your list doesnt contain any element inside it. you need to iterate the inner list to set the values for the `list`.

Comment: where OP is iterating empty list? Iterating empty list doesn't throw this Exception.

Comment: Re-frame this line *exception on iterating the empty list*

Answer (score 4):

Do not use `list.set(index, element)` on a nonexistent element, since it replaces the old (nonexistent) element with a new one and returns the old one. Instead, use `list.add(index, element)` and it will work.

Answer (score 0):

I thingk u have mistake here

list.**get(0)**.set(placeHolder.get(k), (int) (Math.random() * (99999) + 1));

The java.util.ArrayList.get(int index) method returns the element at the specified position in this list.

You are setting just to first element in the list arrray

Answer (score 0):

Here, the main problem is Array indexing and real logic indexing difference...

Start with facts that *ArrayList **not start** with index 0*

*
but in your logic when you use **X.add("Y")** with i = 0 then logic can not find place 0 or can not recover position element 0;
*

that means ... it show indexing error of outbound;

solution ;

first solution : use **i<** istead of **i<=** 
second solution : use **i = 1** for initialization instead of **i = 0;**